# When to send changeReport for EndpointHealth?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

In the "State and change reporting requirements" document, there are requirements mentioned regarding the ChangeReport.

(See in https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smarthome/wwa-skill-requirements.html#state-reporting-requirements)

Based on my understanding, you need to send a ChangeReport when the connectivity of the device changes to UNREACHABLE or OK.

Now, we are applying for WWA certification and want to send a ChangeReport for EndpointHealth for a camera, and unsure about when to send it.

Should it be within 3 seconds after every power on/power off, or within 3 seconds after our cloud service determines that the camera is online/offline?

I tried to find WWA test cases for CameraStreamController.And there are one test case 'disconnect the camera by pulling the plug. Then wait two (2) minutes.' to test connectivity.

This seems to imply that the changeReport only needs to be sent within 2 minutes of power off.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing Alexa.EndpointHealth  is optional, except in the following cases:

- You must implement Alexa.EndpointHealth for devices that are sensors, such as motion sensors and temperature sensors.
- You must implement Alexa.EndpointHealth for your device if you plan to pursue certification in the Works with Alexa or Certified for Humans program

Apart of this exceptions, Alexa.EndpointHealth is optional, we recommend that you always implement Alexa.EndpointHealth to provide the best experience for your users.  As a best practice, we also recommends to support as many EndpointHealth properties as you can.

You will find more information on the requirements and the Alexa.EndpointHealth in the following documentation:

https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smarthome/wwa-skill-requirements.html#skill-reqt

https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/device-apis/alexa-endpointhealth.html

Alexa needs to receive ChangeReports within 3 seconds regardless of your servers considering the camera offline or not, so you should send the ChangeReport as soon as a user turned on/off.

Comment: The requirement mentions "If the connectivity of the device changes to OK, send the report in three seconds or less.". My understanding is that the device should send a changeReport within 3 seconds of being connected to the Internet, not within 3 seconds of the user turning it on, because it can take a few seconds to connect to the Internet.